# Flutter SQFlite if exists in table check function

Tags: flutter, search, sqflite, flutter-futurebuilder, favorites

I am new in flutter and I would be grateful for your help! Right now I am stuck on adding Favorite feature. The problem is that I need the color to change if it already exists in table. I have a ready map for search function and a table made using sqflite. I dont use futurebuilder due to that I cant use async/await.
here is my page with search function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testshared/database/sql_helper.dart';

class MyApp extends  StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MyAppState createState()  => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  Map<String, String> myMap = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key6": "value1",
    "key7": "value2",
    "key8": "value3",
    "key9": "value4",
    "key10": "value5",
    "key11": "value1",
    "key12": "value2",
    "key13": "value3",
    "key14": "value4",
    "key15": "value5",
  };

  List<MapEntry<String, String>> filteredEntries = [];
  bool isExist = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filteredEntries = myMap.entries.toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      color: Colors.greenAccent[700],
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 3,
          backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent[700],
          title: TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              hintText: 'Enter your word',
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onSubmitted: (query) {
              setState(() {
                filteredEntries = myMap.entries
                    .where((entry) =>
                entry.key.contains(query) ||
                    entry.value.contains(query))
                    .toList();
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder (
                itemCount: filteredEntries.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  MapEntry<String, String> entry = filteredEntries[index];
                  String key = entry.key;
                  String value = entry.value;
                    return ListTile(
                      title: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: (key),
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: (value),
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        DatabaseHelper.instance.add(
                          ReadyDict(word: entry.key, description: entry.value),
                        );
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my sqflite database page

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class ReadyDict {
  final int? id;
  final String word;
  final String description;

  ReadyDict({this.id, required this.word, required this.description});

  factory ReadyDict.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReadyDict(
    id: json['id'],
    word: json['word'],
    description: json['description'],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return{
      'word': word,
      'description': description,
    };
  }
}

class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'words.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE words(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    word TEXT,
    description TEXT
    createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)""");
  }

  Future<List<ReadyDict>> getItems() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var words = await db.query('words', orderBy: 'id DESC');
    List<ReadyDict> wordsList = words.isNotEmpty
    ? words.map((c) => ReadyDict.fromMap(c)).toList()
    : [];
    return wordsList;
  }

  Future<int> add(ReadyDict readyDict) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert('words', readyDict.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> remove(String word) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete('words', where: 'word LIKE ?', whereArgs: ['%$word%']);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItem(String key) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return db!.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM words WHERE word = "$key"');
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> checkFavourite(var key) async {
    final Database db = await instance.database;
    return db!.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM words WHERE word = "$key"');
  }
}
```

I am new in stackoverflow too, so if I had some mistakes in my question I am sorry, Thank you!

I have tried to use checkFavourite function, it was in answer for another question, but that doesnt work cause when I call that with await it ask to be in async. Do i need to create another table with unsaved words and make a search field using textfield + dart.io to use futurebuilder?
Thank you!

Comment: are you trying to fetch items from sqflite db and update favorite color based on cheeked state?

Comment: I am trying to compare key of filteredentries with my items in table, so if there is an item with same key, it should change the color of icon. I hope that we understan each other.

Comment: `items in table` sqlite data ?

Comment: not that, i saw almost the same question on stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72600124/flutter-implement-a-favorites-feature-using-sqlite/75197581#75197581. That doesnt work for me cause i dont use futurebuilder so i asked if the same thing i can do without using futurebuilder.

Comment: It has to be async because inserting and querying in table is async task. you have to see yourself that how you will handle async task there are various method future builder is one of them.